# Having problems replacing a string...to what i want

Tags: java, string, replace

I managed to get a json response back from a request and i convert it to String lets say:

```
String response = client.execute(get, handler);
```

The response looks something like:

```
"geometry":{"rings":[[[29470.26099999994,40220.076999999583],[29551.560999999754,40324.093000000343],[29597.470999999903,40391.253000000492],[29619.849999999627,40434.842000000179],[29641.708999999799,40471.713999999687],[29701.501000000164,40574.616000000387],[29722.775999999605,40611.230000000447],[29723.673000000417,40613.234999999404]]]}
```

But I want to have it to look like the following one:

```
"Coordinates":"29470.26099999994|40220.076999999583,29551.560999999754|40324.093000000343,29597.470999999903|40391.253000000492,45360.235000003|41478.4790000003,45360.2369999997|41478.4729999993,45353.8320000004|41470.7339999992,45372.21|41468.057,45371.8090000004|41467.1390000004"
```

In summary i want to change the comma between two coordinates in a [ ] set to be separated by pipes"|" instead of comma and to separate a set of two coordinates with ,  instead of "],["

What i tried:

```
response = response.replace("],[","\,");  
response = response.replace("[[[","\"");  
response = response.replace("]]]","\"");
```

However it does not give me what i wanted...becuz i have no idea to achieve the replace of pipe...tot of using regex but dont know how to. can someone help me please

Comment: Write a simple main function which reproduces the problem.

Comment: replace does not use regexes...

Comment: Maybe a bit off the subject but it seems you are trying to parse JSON string. Why not using a JSON parser to get a Java object and then implement the toString method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
String response = "[[[29470.26099999994,40220.076999999583],[29551.560999999754,40324.093000000343],[29597.470999999903,40391.253000000492],[29619.849999999627,40434.842000000179],[29641.708999999799,40471.713999999687],[29701.501000000164,40574.616000000387],[29722.775999999605,40611.230000000447],[29723.673000000417,40613.234999999404]]]";

response = response.replace(",", "|");
response = response.replace("]|[", ",");
response = response.replace("[[[", "\"");
response = response.replace("]]]", "\"");
System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Thanks this totally works. v straightforward. But may i know if there are any constraints using this compare to Gab answer? Gab

Comment: No constraint, just gonna be slower (4 full parsing of all the string instead of 2 and regexp are generally much more performant particulary if you use precompiled patterns).

Comment: Yes, I think they both work. Gab's solution performs better, mine is easier to grab. I'm voting up @Gab to balance :-)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
String result = response.replaceAll("([^\\]])(\\,)","$1\\|").replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","");
```

=> ([^\\]])(\\,) => `([^\])(\,)` every comma not preceded by ]

=> [\\[\\]] => [`\[\]`] every [ or ]

Please note that

- replacing using regexp is using String.replaceAll or `Pattern` class
- String are immutable

Comment: Hi i tried ur solution and almost get what i wanted but just that some slight difference. Mind explaining what does all ur symbol in the ()does?,so i may do some adjustments

Comment: Currently ur answer will replace the middle comma of two coordinates to | by it does it wrongly: [12345.123,34567.12],[23456.23,4567] will become: 12345.12|4567.12,23445.2|567

Comment: ah yes, the surrouding chars are captured too, see edit

Comment: To increase performance you should precompile the patterns : `static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);` `p.matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)`

Comment: it works now but i can only marked one as answer...Thanks Gab.